React Js , Next Js - Unable to serve cache image while doing Image sequencing in Next js / react js
I want to preload create image sequencing using next js and framer motion
I have the code to run the image sequencing it works fine the issue lies in preloading the image and then serving the same
I saw in network tab that the image are preloaded properly but when I scroll the image they are loading individually one after the another and when i scroll reverse it loads again
the typescript code for this is below
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from './ImageSequencing.module.scss';

const imageSequence = Array.from(
  { length: 65 },
  (_, i) =>
    `/home/imageSequencingResult/website rough animation${String(
      i + 1,
    ).padStart(4, '0')}_result.webp`,
);

export default function Home() {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [loadingPercentage, setLoadingPercentage] = useState(0);
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(imageSequence[0]);
  const [loadedImage, setLoadedImage] = useState<HTMLImageElement[]>([]);

  const totalHeight = imageSequence.length * 10 + 15; // Assuming each image is 100vh

  const loadImage = (src: string): Promise<string> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const img = new window.Image();
      img.src = src;
      img.onload = () => resolve(src);
      img.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
      img.onprogress = (event) => {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
          const percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
          setLoadingPercentage(Math.round(percent));
        }
      };
    });

  const loadImages = async () => {
    try {
      await Promise.all(imageSequence.map((src) => loadImage(src)));
      setLoaded(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading images:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadImages();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const index = Math.min(
        imageSequence.length - 1,
        Math.floor(
          (window.scrollY / window.innerHeight) * imageSequence.length,
        ),
      );
      console.log(index, 'index');
      setCurrentImage(imageSequence[index]);
      setScrollY(window.scrollY);
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(loadedImage, 'loadedImage');

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper} style={{ height: `${totalHeight}vh` }}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {!loaded && <div className={styles.loader}>Loading...</div>}
        {loaded && (
          <div className={styles.imageWrapper}>
            <Image
              src={currentImage}
              alt={`Image ${imageSequence.indexOf(currentImage)}`}
              width={1920} // Adjust width and height as per your image dimensions
              height={1080}
              layout="responsive"
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


just for reference this is the scss code
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh; /* Adjust as needed */
  // overflow: hidden; /* Ensure no scrollbars appear */
  position: relative;

  .container {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh; /* Adjust as needed */
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .imageWrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh; /* Adjust as needed */

      > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }

  .loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
  }
}

I also tried to load all the images using this but same result
 <div
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: -1,
            visibility: 'hidden',
            height: 0,
            width: 0,
          }}
        >
          {imageSequence.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Image
                src={item}
                alt={`Image ${index}`}
                width={0} // Adjust width and height as per your image dimensions
                height={0}
                // layout="responsive"
                onLoadStart={() => setLoaded(false)}
                onLoadingComplete={() => setLoaded(true)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div> 

also this
const loadImage = (src: string): Promise<string> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = () => resolve(src);
    img.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
    img.onprogress = (event) => {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        const percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        setLoadingPercentage(Math.round(percent));
      }
    };
  });


